# Problems on measure of angles and arcs in a circle diagram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

A friend of mine recommended this site. I cannot figure out any of the parts in the problem in the picture [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNwH4.jpg)

The line segments AE and DE are not tangent to the circle, so I don't know where to even begin. Is there a theorem I can use to solve these?

Comment: "assume that the lines that look tangent are tangent" looks like a joke...

Answer (score 1):

Draw lines $AD$ and $BC$.

Prove that triangles $AED$ and $BCE$ are similar, with $AE$ corresponding to $CE$, $DE$ corresponding to $BE$ and $AD$ corresponding to $BC$.

Proving that requires a knowledge of the properties of a cyclic quadrilateral.